Pnp-DisableDevice Instance ID coming back as null value
We have a problem at our business where Intel Display driver version 31.0.101.* keeps superseding any new version, and driver 31 is a known problem with Citrix and other tools the organization uses. Intel says on their support page about this known problematic driver to keep 31 installed, but beam down driver revision 32.0.101.* from their site. I want to implement an SCCM script that (since a bunch of machines already have driver 32 installed and just switched back to driver 31 after mandatory update days) disables driver 31 and enables driver 32.
My current code snippet is this:
$Driver31 = "31.0.101."
$Driver32 = "32.0.101."

$oldDriver = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object { $_.Version -like $Driver31 }

$newDriver = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object { $_.Version -like $Driver32 }

if ($oldDriver) {
    Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $oldDriver.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
}

When this is run, I receive an error saying the .InstanceId is a null value. What am I doing wrong here?

PowerShell won't give you hints if you try to get a property that doesn't exist, so you are not receiving any feedback when you query on a non-existent $_.Version property. To check the properties that are available, run:
Get-PnpDevice | Get-Member

This returns a list of properties - of which Version is not an option:
Name                        MemberType     Definition
----                        ----------     ----------
Class                       AliasProperty  Class = PNPClass
FriendlyName                AliasProperty  FriendlyName = Name
InstanceId                  AliasProperty  InstanceId = DeviceID
Problem                     AliasProperty  Problem = ConfigManagerErrorCode

So you have to first find the devices you are interested in, with a query like:
$devices = Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like "*Intel*"}

Then make use of the Get-PnpDeviceProperty cmdlet on each Instance to find Instances that have the old driver version - for example for the first device found:
$version = Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId $device.InstanceId | Where-Object { $_.KeyName -like '*Version*'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Data

(Run the command through adding each piped section at a time to get an idea of the intermediate steps here)
Then use Disable-PnpDevice when you find the devices you want to disable.

Alternatively there may be a way to do this using Get-CimInstance - I've just answered why you're getting the null value error

Thank you for your response! I was able to revise my script to fix the original error, however, I now receive this error message:
`Disable-PnpDevice : Generic failure
At line:20 char:9


    Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$fa ...



    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Win32_PnPEntity..._330817AA&R...):ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity) [Disable-PnpDevice], CimException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice`




No worries - it might be worth posting another question - it is hard to tell but maybe you haven't accurately filtered devices and are attempting to disable a device that can't be disabled? Try re-confirming devices using Get-PnpDevice before disabling them
